# How to have a SELECT query prepared in CQL using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

Like I can prepare `INSERT` query, how can I prepare `SELECT` query in CQL-Python?
INSERT statement:

```
insert_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "INSERT INTO  {} ({}, {}, {}) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
            )
        )
```

And execute it with:

```
params = (key, "version_1", row, )
                futures.append(
                    (
                        insert_sql,
                        params
                    )
                )
            # Checking whether the formed keys already exists
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, concurrency=1000, raise_on_first_error=False
            )
```

When I do the same with `SELECT`:

```
select_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=%s AND {}=%s AND {}!=%s"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
            )
        )
```

And execute it with:

```
params = (key, "version_1", row, )
                futures.append(
                    (
                        select_sql,
                        params
                    )
                )
            # Checking whether the formed keys already exists
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, concurrency=1000, raise_on_first_error=False
            )
```

I face an error:

```
cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported "!=" relation: row != ?"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getting_started.py", line 145, in <module>
    example1.insert_data()
  File "getting_started.py", line 97, in insert_data
    self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2405, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2402, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4062, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported "!=" relation: row != ?"
```

And after changing `!=` to `NOT` as in the code:

```
select_query = (
                "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=%s AND {}=%s AND NOT {}=%s"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
            )
        print(select_query)
        select_sql = self.session.prepare(
            select_query
        )
        for df in chunks:
            futures = []
            df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
            chunk_counter += 1
            for row in df:
                key = str(row["0"])
                row = json.dumps(row, default=str)
                params = (key, "version_1", row, )
                futures.append(
                    (
                        select_sql,
                        params
                    )
                )
            # Checking whether the formed keys already exists
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, concurrency=1000, raise_on_first_error=False
            )
            for (success, result) in results:
                if not success:
                    self.handle_error(result)
                print(result)
                sys.exit()
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, concurrency=1000, raise_on_first_error=False)
            for (success, result) in results:
                if not success:
                    self.handle_error(result)  # result will be an Exception
            if (chunk_counter % 1000 == 0):
                self.log.info(
                    "{} 's Batch Insert Completed".format(chunk_counter))
            # print(
            #     str(chunk_counter*chunksize) + " : " +
            #     str(datetime.utcnow() - start_time)
            # )
        print("Complete task's duration is: {}".format(
            datetime.utcnow() - start_time))
```

I get this:

```
etting_started.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  from cassandra.cluster import BatchStatement, Cluster
2019-01-19 19:49:16,582 [INFO] root: setting keyspace...
SELECT * FROM TenMillion WHERE id=%s AND version=%s AND NOT row=%s
2019-01-19 19:49:16,590 [ERROR] cassandra.cluster: Error preparing query:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2402, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4062, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:34 no viable alternative at character '%'">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getting_started.py", line 147, in <module>
    example1.insert_data()
  File "getting_started.py", line 100, in insert_data
    select_query
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2405, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2402, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4062, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:34 no viable alternative at character '%'">
```

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra doesn't seem to support `!=` with `SELECT`

Check here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html

You will have to write a query without `!=` and managed the logic in your code.

Comment: What is the other way round for this operation? I am falling short or alternatives.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the IN operator and give the set of values which are acceptable instead of giving the "!="?

Comment: So for 1000 rows, I need to have 1000 possible values in each row parameter for the query for using the IN operator. That means 1000000 times the memory of `!=` operator. That would literally slow down my speed and OOM error will not be far away.

Comment: How many possible values for "row" column are present in your data? If each row column will have different value, then why don't you use the = operator? Can you update some more information about your cassandra table and it's schema?

Comment: Its a row from a csv file, any value is possible. In my version 1, I get 10Million rows and insert it in Cassandra, next run could bring me 14Million rows and I need to know which ones were already existing in it. Hence, I need to make a select query so as to know whether the incoming data has a new row(hence update) or the same row(no action then).
Table schema is: id, version, row with id and version as PK.

Answer (score 1):

The error gives you back message="Unsupported "!=". "!=" is not supported. Try changing the SELECT code to:

```
select_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=%s AND {}=%s AND NOT {}=%s"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
            )
        )
```

Comment: Hey @Frans! Why would you change `?` to `%s`?

Comment: Also, your method is returning an error: `cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:34 no viable alternative at character '%'">`

Comment: I suggested to change AND {}!=%s to AND NOT ()=%s. Suppose self.table_name = 'tablename' this will result in a query like: 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=%s AND version=%s AND NOT row=%s'.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your comment. You wrote `()` instead of `{}`.

Comment: The latest error is about the %s in the query. You don't fill in theses variables resulting in an error.

Comment: As you can check from my code, I do fill all variables suitably. There are 3 `%s` in the select query and in the params list, I give 3 values: `id`, `version`, `row`.

Comment: I printed the query, its `SELECT * FROM TenMillion WHERE id=%s AND version=%s AND NOT row=%s`

Comment: If you change  you code to the example below to errors should be gone and result in a query like:     

SELECT * FROM TenMillion WHERE id=id_value AND version=vesion_value AND NOT row=row_value     

 select_sql = self.session.prepare(
        (
            "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}={} AND {}={} AND NOT {}={}"
        ).format(
            self.table_name, "id", "id_value", "version", "version_value", "row", "row_value"
        )

Comment: `select_sql = self.session.prepare( ( "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=? AND {}=? AND NOT {}=?" ).format( self.table_name, "id", "version", "row" ) )` results into: `cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:54 no viable alternative at input 'NOT' (...? AND version=? AND [NOT]...)">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186971/discussion-between-frans-and-aviral-sanjay).